# EXCEL: SUMIFS with multiple identifiers

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, sumifs

I have the following situation in excel on a much bigger scale, but for the purposes of this question, here is what it looks like:

```
Identifier  Merged Identifier  Person A  Person B  Person C  
Code1       MCode1             $amount   $amount   $amount  
Code2       MCode1             $amount   $amount   $amount  
Code3       MCode3             $amount   $amount   $amount
```

Essentially, I have individuals with dollars associated to certain codes. Some codes have dollar amounts small enough such that they need to be merged into one dollar amount. I created the merged identifier column to dictate which codes align together. When a code is not merged, the identifier and merged identifiers are equal (Code3 = MCode3).

The challenge I am having is that I need to go through a huge database at a Code level, determine if that code is a part of a merged code, and then sum the dollar amounts of the entire merged code for that particular person. At first I tried something like this:

```
SUMIFS(C2:E4, B2:B4, B2, A2:4, A2)
```

but the columns and rows don't match so I get the #VAL error. I'm a little stuck on this one, so would love some help.

Cheers,
G

Comment: I'm not sure if I got the problem right: The results should be 1 Sum per person, that sum all amounts in the column titled as that person, in whichs rows the MCode = Code?

Answer (score 0):

Take a step back to an old style array formula.

```
=SUM(IF(A2:A4=F9,IF(B2:B4=G9,C2:E4)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sumproduct is a very interesting function. Normally you can multiply arrays and get the total. For example (1,2,3) x (2,3,4) = 2+6+12 = 20

But the part that can help you is, instead of giving it plain values, you can multiply an array of values with an array or True / Falses. Your 1st and 2nd columns will be converted to 1s and 0s (1 if the case is true, 0 if it's false)

[image: sumproduct as an alternative to sumifs]https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxd96.png

=SUMPRODUCT(--(($A$2:$A$4)=$A$7),--(($B$2:$B$4)=$B$7),F$2:F$4)

what this becomes is
(1,0,0) x (1,1,0) x (6,15,24) = 6